# Есть ли сочетания клавиш для показа краткой справки о функции в visual studio 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Если в редакторе кода с++ в vs 2019 навести курсор на функцию, появится такая справка:

[image: справка о функции]

Если начать вводить аргументы функции, появляется другая справка:

[image: справка об аргументах]

Есть ли сочетания клавиш в vs, чтобы отобразить эти 2 справки? Смотрел в интернете и в параметрах клавиатуры, но так ничего и не нашёл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первую можно вызвать Edit → Intelli Sense → Quick Info.

Вторая Edit → Intelli Sense → Parameter Info.

Ну и там будут указаны горячие клавиши, назначенные на эти действия.